# Set alarms as reminders for Microsoft Band from desktop application

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm developing a Windows desktop application which connects with a Microsoft Band to set alarms as reminders but I cannot find API to do that, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the alarms functionality within the Band is not exposed via the SDK.  You will have to create a phone application that wakes up at such scheduled times and uses the SDK to send notifications to a custom Tile and/or haptic notifications.